# How can i import a json file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to import a json  file when i call `$(document).ready(function (){}` . That properties defined in the json file are needed for my html form.
How can i do that?

Comment: try this `$.getJSON('path', function(data){ console.log(data); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example how to do this could be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $.getJSON('names.json',function(data){
            console.log('success');
            $.each(data.employees,function(i,emp){
                $('ul').append('<li>'+emp.firstName+' '+emp.lastName+'</li>');
            });
        }).error(function(){
            console.log('error');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
  $.getJSON( "path to json file", function( data ) {
      var item = [];
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        item.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
      });

      $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "myclass",
        html: item.join( "" )
      }).appendTo( "body" );
    });
```